# Pass data between EXE/DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I have DLL and EXE app. DLL is registered in EXE. Then in EXE instance of class `A` is created as `shared_ptr`. Next, this instance is passed to the DLL and method `example` of this instance is called on DLL side.

```
class Result
{
//Some attributes e.g std::vector
}

class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}

    Result example(){
        Result r;
        //Fill data in r object....
        return r;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when `example` is called somewhere in DLL :

```
void someDLLMethod()
{
    //a is a shared pointer of A class
    {
        Result r = a->example();
    }//PROBLEM IS HERE DURING DEALLOCATING Result OBJECT

    //some stuff...
}
```

It seems that the problem occurs during deleting `r` object. I understand when I will try to allocate some memory in EXE and then try to deallocate this memory in DLL then memory issues can occur, but in this case, `Result` object is copied from EXE to DLL. Also, vector stored in `Result` object doesn't contain any pointers so it should be deep copy of vector. 
One solution is to allocate `Result` object in DLL, pass it as reference to called method and fill all necessary data, but I want to get copy as result.
Why this problem occurs? How it is possible to fix it? EXE and DLL are in this same solution of Visual studio and must be compiled with \MT or \MTd and there is no possibility to change it.

Comment: Do **not** compile with /MT, you absolutely must use /MD to bring this to a good end.

Answer (score 0):

Memory for the vector is being allocated in the DLL and free'd in the exe as the vector is probably using move semantics in its return (or even just RVO) which just moves the pointer to the allocated internals. As you're using a static CRT this means the memory is being allocated with one crt and free'd with a different instance which leads to badness.

Short story - don't do this. Exposing C++ objects across DLL boundaries is bad. You should use a C interface or an interface that is designed for this - e.g. WinRT.

If you do choose to expose c++ objects across a DLL interface you must make sure that both the EXE and the DLL use the same version of the compiler and you link with /MD. If you can't use /MD you'll never get this to work reliably.

Sure you could pre-allocate the vector and fill it in in the call but that's just masking the issue until things inevitably change down the line.